# Update SQL Query to add rows from a single table but combine 1 columns values togethor

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query that will select a list of items that have the same information in all the columns except 1, a Total # of Units.  I need the query to combine those rows.

Example Columns

In the table I have 3 rows that look like this:

```
Date    item # Description  qty
---------------------------------
20150910  1233    lettuce   1.20
20150910  1234    cheese    3.40
20150910  1234    cheese    2.65
20150910  1234    cheese    1.00
```

I want to run an update query to update the table to look like this:

```
20150910, 1233, lettuce, 1.20
20150910, 1234, cheese, 7.05
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is just a grouped summation, except that you want to do the deletion. Instead of deleting the old rows, it is actually easier to just insert the data into a new table with the same schema, or rename the existing table to Table_Old.

You can then select the summary data from the old table with:

```
SELECT Code, Id, Description, SUM(Amount) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY Code, Id, Description
```

This way you also have the old data as a backup, in case you mess it up! :)

Comment: Thanks Emi and Justin, But how do I update the table with the new summed totals?

Comment: @BradJarrett, I've just editted my answer take a look and tell us how it went

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sum qty

```
SELECT Date, Item, Description, SUM(qty)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Date, Item, Description
```

Edit: For updating the table, assuming you have no negative values in qty, I'd do

```
UPDATE your_table yt
SET yt.qty = (SELECT SUM(yt2.qty)
           FROM your_table yt2
           WHERE yt.date = yt2.date and yt.Item=yt2.Item AND yt.Description = yt2.Description);

DELETE FROM your_table yt
WHERE qty <> (SELECT MAX(yt2.qty)
              FROM your_table yt2
              WHERE yt.date = yt2.date and yt.Item=yt2.Item AND yt.Description = yt2.Description);
```

This should do the trick, first you sum it and then delete every row that has qty different from the one you have just sumed.

Note that you don't need to group by in the subqueries as you're filtering the items you are updating/deleting

Comment: Thanks EMI, but I get an incorrect syntax on line 1 near dc, 7 near dc and 10 near ;....here is the actual script:UPDATE dailyinventorycounts dc

SET dc.totalunits = (SELECT SUM(dc2.totalunits)
  FROM dailyinventorycounts dc2
  WHERE dc.yyyymmdd = dc2.yyyymmdd and dc.[item code]= dc2.[item code] and dc.[desc]= dc2.[desc]);

DELETE FROM dailyinventorycounts dc
WHERE TotalUnits <> (SELECT MAX(dc2.totalunits)
  FROM inventorycounts dc2
  WHERE dc.yyyymmdd = dc2.yyyymmdd and dc.[item code]= dc2.[item code] and dc.[desc] = dc2.[desc];

Comment: I used qoutes (") instead of brackets ([]) and it worked for me. I'm using Oracle dbms, what's yours?

Comment: You need to close the brackets at the end of the second query and I think sql server doesn't end queries with semicolon (;)

Comment: I got it to run using removing the dc.  However, it took all the TotalUnits and multiplied them by several thousands....I know have Total Units of 10976340.375 in every row but it did not combine the like rows...